# Pycrypto: How to view raw RSA signature data?

Tags: python, encryption, rsa, pycrypto

I'm working with a service that uses raw RSA with a private key to sign a payload. The data is effectively produced using:

```
openssl rsautl -inkey private_key.pem -raw -sign
```

(Also, the result of encrypting with the private key)

Unfortunately, in Pycrypto the corresponding `.verify()` method only takes an argument to verify the data against to return true or false.

In openssl, this could be achieved with one of the following:

```
# Private key based
openssl rsautl -inkey private_key.pem -raw -verify
# Public key based
openssl rsautl -inkey public_key.pem -pubin -raw -verify
```

How can I achieve the same functionality in Pycrypto?

(I understand the risks of raw RSA. A custom padding mechanism has been implemented to mitigate some of those risks. Unfortunately, it's not possible to change the current implementation)

Comment: FWIW, it's possible to access the OpenSSL library directly in Python by using the `ctypes` module. However, you do need to negotiate the rabbit warren of the OpenSSL docs and header files. ;) [Here](https://gist.github.com/PM2Ring/ac1d31d7391c94410c142d5a059b4cda) is an example that shows how to do some simple AES tasks that way.

Comment: thanks @PM2Ring. I'm lucky that I could solve this with native code, but your example is a really neat example of ctypes, which I'm sure to use in the future

Comment: In the title you have the word 'view'. Did you mean 'verify'?

Comment: Hi @JamesKPolk. The problem is that I essentially want to **see** the result of the decryption of the signature using the public key. The verify function of Pycrypto does not allow me to see the result, only check it against a known value. In some circumstances I don't have a know the value to check against or I simply want to see the result of a private key encryption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delving into the `.verify()` method, one can find how Pycrypto builds the verification signature before comparing it to the given required signature.

It essentially uses Python's `pow()` method with the key's public (*e*) and the key's modulus (*n*). You will first need to pack the secret message into a (long) integer and then convert the result back to bytes. Fortunately, Pycrypto provides everything you need.

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Util import number

key = RSA.importKey(private_key_str, key_password_str)

# The message must be packed as a long first.
secret_message_long = number.bytes_to_long(secret_message_bytes)
# The magic!        
verify_long = pow(encrypted_session_key_long, key.e, key.n)
# and back to bytes
verify_bytes = number.long_to_bytes(result_long)

# Convert message back to a str (Unicode str in Py2).
# Replace 'utf-8' with the correct encoding for *your* message!!!!!
verify_str = verify_bytes.decode('utf-8')
```