# Python RSA sign a string with NONEWithRSA

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa, pycrypto, pycryptodome

I am working on a project in which client side code is in Java and they are using `NONEWithRSA` algorithm to sign and verify a string.

I am using `PyCryptodome` to generate sign for a given string. https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/signature/pkcs1_v1_5.html

But I have not found it uses `NONEWithRSA` algorithm so its giving different signature than what my clients expects on the server.

Do any library on python supports this algorithm?

Comment: Relevant issue: https://github.com/Legrandin/pycryptodome/issues/274

Comment: @sshashank124 Does this mean it is not supported in python ??

Comment: I can't know for sure. You will just have to search online.

Comment: Hashing before a signature is a necessary part of the security of signature. Java, for some reason, that not clear for me, provides RSA signatures and other signatures without hashing. This doesn't mean that it is secure. Stop using the `NONEWithRSA` and prefer SHA series. PyCryptodome is good in this issue since the don't let the people on the wrong way.

Comment: Is there any chance you can just get the server-side code instead of trying to figure out what is needed one little step at a time?

Comment: @kelalaka It's mainly present to allow persons to implement their own way of hashing, e.g. there was an OpenSSL "hash" that combined SHA-1 and MD-5 within the PKCS#1 v1.5 padding but without the DER encoded hash indication, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica I've suspected that but waited for someone has some knowledge about this. Thanks.

Comment: In the end this is just plaintext RSA. From the [standard names document](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/specs/security/standard-names.html#signature-algorithms): "The RSA signature algorithm which does not use any digesting algorithm and uses only the RSASP1/RSAVP1 primitives as defined in PKCS #1 v2.2.". This is by the way not *entirely* correct, obviously it also performs the I2OSP and OS2IP functions to encode large integers from and to bytes.

Comment: All the toolkits seem to keep to PKCS#1 v1.5 of PSS signatures. I even found requests on GitHub where the feature to use the "raw" RSA signature is deliberatey *not* accepted. I'd guess you would need to use specialized libs such as ChillKat or [do the mod exp yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48280670/589259). @kelalaka A modern use would be RSA-KEM of course, although that one is  for encryption. Older schemes such as ISO 979 - uh 6 or 7 - signatures would be another.

Comment: Ugh, sorry for the many comments. I think you have to compile a function like [this one (PyCryptoDome `_encrypt`)](https://github.com/Legrandin/pycryptodome/blob/41300af203a1a0b24df83b1060e5068d0f9076cf/lib/Crypto/PublicKey/RSA.py#L150) which uses CRT parameters to "encrypt" a padded hash. I guess Python needs an "Extreme Hazmat" library :|

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica so the conclusion is we dont have any library on python that supports NONEWithRSA for now . If I have to implement it what might be the solution ??

Comment: Well, there must be libraries out there (such as Chilkat2 for Python), but that's payware. However, I cannot find it in the standard libs. So my advice is to lift it from an implementation of PKCS#1 v1.5 or OAEP and hope that it is at least somewhat resistant against side channel attacks... It makes sense maybe to do a bit more research, I might have missed a library...

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica I was unable to find a library that does this. So I wrote that part of code in Java. It works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into this same issue trying to support signature generation for an Android app that expects the equivalent of "NONEwithRSA." In my case, it was actually a situation where the application is using a hash, but it is obviously missing the ASN.1 code prefix.

It turns out that the Java RSA cipher works like magic behind the scenes and automatically uses signature block type PKCS#1 padding (so that each message/key combination produces the same signature).

This caused me problems because I initially thought I could just encrypt the raw hash using the private key in Python, and then it would be compatible with Java. However, encrypting with the private key in PyCryptodome uses encryption block type PKCS#1 which causes a v15 unpad exception when verifying with Java.

The simplest solution I found was to use the rsa package (https://pypi.org/project/rsa/) and directly access some of its internal methods.

```
    key = rsa.PrivateKey.load_pkcs1(
        RSA.import_key(base64.b64decode(private_key)).export_key()
    )
    keylength = rsa.pkcs1.common.byte_size(key.n)
    padded = rsa.pkcs1._pad_for_signing(message, keylength)
    payload = rsa.pkcs1.transform.bytes2int(padded)
    encrypted = key.blinded_encrypt(payload)
    block = rsa.pkcs1.transform.int2bytes(encrypted, keylength)
    signature = base64.b64encode(block).decode()
```

Essentially, this code originates in the rsa/pkcs1.py module's "sign_hash" method. We just do not add the ASN.1 code.

This solution is admittedly fragile, but it should give you a good working reference to make something more robust.

### Validation

This Python signature generation procedure produces an identical signature to the Java "NONEwithRSA" algorithm for the same key/input.

```
private_key = "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"
```

```
message = "PLWReC8yuVEViE6kpS9tV2ueldyruoCMBLthuPgKDnw="
```

Decode the message from base 64 to a byte array in each language. The previously supplied Python signing method will produce the following signature:

```
signature_result = "WhM77ROa7Dl0HmO6QdMQjkQ336N2gfi4c2QuLKkIHtxWZQDm7xmLbzbcVxzN3A6hrSdZIS/v5HIpuLe5MovEno6t5QhTyONL4J0evYeO3Ou784qQZORXRlgoOCbkZu25Ty9hBy043HaeUprkOC5f7hcJjRmrel1+izD25NFEDreCnC3paPJqzMXQyUI6gioqdaxth3H0lRW9rAu4pgH/Hgt0/ljd0ch8FJPhfEUNKAV6wltp4h53D9gSlJVBCW2/VFDpzfTHkgkNK+egA2GTc/glWKQ0jm2tEVWniR9nia2bJfNJ/LWrr19ktejex+7g93569HX8w+jp6dAlSIMk9Q=="
```

The following Java code produces the same result:

```
    Signature instance = Signature.getInstance("NONEwithRSA");
    instance.initSign(privateKey);
    instance.update(Base64.decode(data, Base64.NO_WRAP));
    byte[] signature = instance.sign();
    String b64Signature = Base64.encodeToString(signature, Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use the library `cryptography` with [Prehashed](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/utils/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.utils.Prehashed).

This will assume your data is already the output of a hash (so it will not add extra hashing):

```
import hashlib
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding, rsa, utils

private_key = rsa.generate_private_key(
    public_exponent = 65537,
    key_size = 2048,
    backend = default_backend()
)
public_key = private_key.public_key()

# Compute the hash here
prehashed_msg = hashlib.sha256(b"A message I want to sign").digest()

# Sign the hash (do not perform any hashing)
signature = private_key.sign(
    prehashed_msg,
    padding.PSS(
        mgf = padding.MGF1(hashes.SHA256()),
        salt_length = padding.PSS.MAX_LENGTH),
    utils.Prehashed(hashes.SHA256())
)

# Verify
public_key.verify(
    signature,
    prehashed_msg,
    padding.PSS(
        mgf = padding.MGF1(hashes.SHA256()),
        salt_length = padding.PSS.MAX_LENGTH),
    utils.Prehashed(hashes.SHA256())
)
```

Comment: This is not the mode NoneWithRSA that was explicitly requested. Just an RSA example won't do, I'm afraid.